# sql server query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with values

```
ID BarID FName LName ColA ColB ColC

1   22    Jon  Carr   0    2    1
2   23    Don  Brown  1    3    2
3   23    Don  Brown  2    1    2
4   24    A     B     0    2    1
5   24    A     B     2    3    1
6   24    A     B     1    2    3
```

Table name is `Temp`

I want to convert this table into something like this

```
ID BarID FName LName ColA ColB ColC

1   22    Jon  Carr   0    2    1
2   23    Don  Brown  3    4    4
4   24    A     B     3    7    5
```

Last 3 columns (`ColA ColB ColC`) of the duplicate rows (duplicate `BarID`) are summed up (summation)

What sql query can I write in sql server to achieve this?

Comment: We all have deadlines, and we're all here for free. Telling us that it's urgent isn't going to help you.

Comment: Do we assume that all `FName` and `LName` values are equal, for any given `BarID`?

Comment: Please note how this site works: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237/27535

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
   MIN(ID), BarID, FName, LName, SUM(ColA), SUM(ColB), SUM(ColC)
FROM
   Temp
GROUP BY
   BarID, FName, LName
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the GROUP BY

```
SELECT 
   min(id) AS ID, 
   BarID, 
   FName, 
   LName, 
   sum(ColA) AS ColA, 
   sum(ColB) AS ColB, 
   sum(ColC) AS ColC
FROM 
   Temp
GROUP BY 
  BarID, FName, LName
```

Comment: All answers are correct, but this one has a little detail... it contains the correct column aliases

Answer (score 0):

Should be pretty simple with a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT 
    MIN(ID) AS 'ID',
    BarID, FName, LName, 
    SUM(ColA) AS 'ColA',
    SUM(ColB) AS 'ColB',
    SUM(ColC) AS 'ColC'
FROM dbo.Temp
GROUP BY BarID, FName, LName
```

This sums up the columns A, B, and C, and groups by the `BarID, FName, LName`